# Spring JPA doesn't validate bean on update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-validator

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.7, Spring JPA, Hibernate validation, Spring Data REST, Spring HATEOAS.

I've a simple bean like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
}
```

As you can see I'm using @NotBlank. According to Hibernate documentation the validation should be made on pre-persist and pre-update.

I created a junit test:

```
@Test(expected = ConstraintViolationException.class)
public void saveWithEmptyNameThrowsException() {  
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("");
    personRepository.save(person);
}
```

this test works fine and therefore the validation process happens correctly. Instead in this test case, the validation doesn't work:

```
@Test(expected = ConstraintViolationException.class)
public void saveWithEmptyNameThrowsException() {
   Person person = new Person();
   person.setName("Name");
   personRepository.save(person);

   person.setName("");
   personRepository.save(person);
}
```

I found another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963022/spring-data-jpa-validation-is-missing-on-update-merge) but unfortunately there isn't any reply.
Why the validation is not made on update() method? Advice to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think ConstraintViolationException is not occurred because during update Hibernate don't flush result to database on the spot. Try to replace in your test save() with saveAndFlush().

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spring Boot JPA test? If yes, `saveWithEmptyNameThrowsException` is wrapped within a transaction, and it will not be committed until the method's execution is done. In other words, the method is treated as one unit of work. Calling`personRepository.save` (unless you enable auto commit/flush changes) will not resort to reflection of your entity changes, but until transaction is committed. Here's a workaround for your test:

```
@Test(expected = ConstraintViolationException.class)
public void saveWithEmptyNameThrowsException() {
   // Wrap the following into another transaction
   // begin
      Person person = new Person();
      person.setName("Name");
      personRepository.save(person);
   // commit

   // Wrap the following into another transaction
   // begin
      person = ... get from persistence context
      person.setName("");
      personRepository.save(person);
   // commit
}
```

You can use `TransactionTemplate` for programmatic transaction demarcation in Spring.